# Temporarily disable a specific option after it has been selected (in any selector) for all instances of that selector in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

I have a html template file for my php code that loops a series of fields (first name, last name, date of birth, ...etc) for 6 people. One of these fields is the 'relationship' selector, and the options are: 'Spouse', or 'Child'. If 'Spouse' is selected, I would like to temporarily disable this option in the relationship selector for ALL people. If no Spouse is selected, this option can be chosen in any of the people's relationship selector.

I am very close to solving the problem. I am using jquery (code below), and the code does what I want it to do. The only problem is that it only looks at the first person in my loop. If I select 'Spouse' for persons 2-6, it still allows me to select this option for any other person in their relationship select. I want it to be disabled for all people if it is selected in any of the options.

```
<table>
    <!-- People -->
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $people_max; $i++) { ?> 
    <tr>
        <td class="title" colspan="2">
            <h2>PERSON <?= $i+1; ?></h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
            ... 
            <tr>
        <td class="name<?= $carl_msg->getFieldMessageStyle($i . '-person_relationship_id'); ?>">Relationship:</td>
        <td class="value">
            <select tabindex="" id="relationship_select" class="select" onchange="disableSpouseOptionWhenSelected()" name="prgm_person[<?= $i; ?>][person_relationship_id]" style="width: 110px;">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach ($selects['people'] as $person) { ?>
                    <option id="option" value="<?= $person['person_relationship_id']; ?>" <?php if ($person['person_relationship_id'] == $html['prgm_person'][$i]['person_relationship_id']) { ?>selected<?php } ?>><?= $person['person_relationship_name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
            ...
            <?php } ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="value">
            <br />

            <!-- Enable the top update buttons -->
            <script language="JavaScript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    disableSpouseOptionWhenSelected();
                });


                function disableSpouseOptionWhenSelected() { 
                    $('select:first').on('change', function () {
                        $('option[value=1]').prop('disabled', this.value === '1');
                    });
                }
            </script>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

....

I have not included all the code in the file, only the relevant parts.

Expected: if the 'Spouse' option inside the relationship_select is selected for the first person, temporarily disable this option for ALL people's relationship_selects. However if 'Spouse' option is selected in persons 2-6, it still allows you to choose this for any other person.

Actual: if the 'Spouse' option inside the relationship_select is selected for ANY person, temporarily disable this option inside ALL of the relationship_select selectors (for each person).

Comment: How the first person can be identified? Does he has unique id or class?

Comment: not all browser support disabled in options.

Comment: @dganenco I want this to work for all people, currently it only works for the first person, therefore I am unsure why their identification is relevant. Inside the loop they are each referenced as prgm_person[<?= $i; ?>][prgm_person_id], only $i would = 0 for the first person.

Comment: First, I don't think you need "onchange" as an element attribute and as an event listener in the function

Comment: @maximus1127 is right. With the onchange attribute set, your function gets called by that attribute for all your selects generated by the loop, your first select then also calls the function via the eventlistener.

Comment: Thank you @maximus1127 and @user3154108! I will remove the redundancy. Makes sense!

Comment: @epascarello sure you aren't thinking about browsers supporting hiding options?

Comment: I also see you have a class that's getting assigned on each <select>. I would just throw an if statement into your disable function. Make sure you have some sort of identifying attribute that catches $i when it's 0, and make your if statement basically say "if 'this.element.id == 0, disable all with class 'select'". That way, if the element is not identified as 0, it is not the first, and does not disable any other elements sharing that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to help you. First of all, as mentioned in comments you have to delete `onchange` handler from loop and you have to make `select` `id` unique. (using `$i` variable). And then after selects had been created you have to handle their changes using [event-delegation api](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Few words about change handler.
If I had correctly understood your requirements You have to disable all 'spouse' options for all non first selects. So handler is checking if the select is the first or not, and if it is is setting `prop('disabled')` based on first select value. Please feel free to correct me if I wrongly understood your requirements.

```js
   $(document).on('change', '.select', function() {
  const selects = $('.select');
  const doesAnyoneIsSpouse = selects.filter(function(key) {
return $(selects[key]).val() === '1';
  }).length > 0;

  $('.select').not(this).find('option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', doesAnyoneIsSpouse);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select tabindex="" id="relationship_select" class="select" name="prgm_person[0][person_relationship_id]" style="width: 110px;">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value='0'>Child</option>
   <option value='1'>Spouse</option>
 </select>

 <select tabindex="" id="relationship_select" class="select" name="prgm_person[1][person_relationship_id]" style="width: 110px;">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value='0'>Child</option>
   <option value='1'>Spouse</option>
 </select>

 <select tabindex="" id="relationship_select" class="select" name="prgm_person[2][person_relationship_id]" style="width: 110px;">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value='0'>Child</option>
   <option value='1'>Spouse</option>
 </select>

 <select tabindex="" id="relationship_select" class="select" name="prgm_person[3][person_relationship_id]" style="width: 110px;">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value='0'>Child</option>
   <option value='1'>Spouse</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me :) I just tried this out and it works very well except for the very first person. If I select 'Spouse' on any of the 2-6 people, it doesn't allow that option to be selected. Great! However, unfortunately, this does not apply to the 1 person, because I could still select it. If I try to add your JS on top of mine (since mine only works on the first and not the rest), it doesn't save the selection altogether.

Comment: Huh, it's still hard to understand you requirements. Let we try one more time. Provide please only your required scenario and try to add few examples.

Comment: My apologies for any confusion! Let me try to reword it! So there are 6 people, all generated by a loop with multiple fields. Relationship is one of them. "Spouse" or "Child". If "Spouse" is selected for any person, disable this option for the rest of the people. Example: Person 1 "Spouse" for relationship dropdown. "Spouse" is now disabled in the relationship dropdown for all other people. Example 2: Person 1 "Child", spouse is still available for other dropdowns. Person 2 "Spouse". spouse is now disabled for all other dropdowns

Comment: @Hana I've updated my answer. I think that now it covers all your requirements.

Comment: this answer is excellent! Does exactly what I asked! an unexpected problem I ran into is it won't allow me to submit this data once disabled to the db... but I think that's out of the scope for this question and probably has to do with the 'disabled' html.

Comment: You are right,  I would update my answer tomorrow with this change.  It's a small one.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out, do you have any advice? I may have to look for an alternate approach

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it. I updated my answer. It works fine now.

Comment: No worries thank you so much! This is perfect!! You've been a great help